# SQL grouping by words LIKE (with wildcards), how to achieve correct sum

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-jet-ace

I am working with an Access query in Excel VBA. 
My table contains a mix of more general and specialised products, a column with strings e.g:

```
    Mountain bike x2321, 10
    Enduro Mountain bike special y3233, 20 
    Mountain bike a2a321, 10
    Skateboard z23233, 10
    Skateboard y2dsf3, 10
    Skadeboard pro advanced special 20, etc
```

I would like to sum total the sales values and I would like to aggregate the sums by categories specified in separate TableB, a dictionary with substrings: (

Mountain Bike Special, 
Mountain Bike
Skateboard pro 
Skateboard.

I sorted the table in the descending order so that the longer names show up before the shorter ones. By sorting expected that JOIN will result in  Scateboard pro will  tested for existence against any record before Scateboard will be tested.

My expected result would be

```
Mountain bike special   Total 20
Mountain bike           Total  20
Skateboard pro Total  20
Skateboard      Total 20
```

However my query totals all the Mountain bikes, even the special ones and all Skateboards, even the pro ones which is incorrect. I would like them to be summed up in separate categories. Sorting descending my TableB, my dictionary did not hepl. :

```
Mountain bike special   Total 20
Mountain bike                 Total  40
Skateboard pro Total  20
Skateboard      Total 40
```

My attempted query includes searching with LIKE and wildcards, it looks as follows:

SELECT  "" As kod, **sum(b) As wartosc**, TableB.Descr as opis_grupy

FROM TableA  LEFT JOIN TableB ON **TableA.Descr LIKE ("*"+TableB.Descr+"*")**

WHERE TableA.a IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY  TableB.Descr

ORDER BY  TableB.Descr DESC

Unfortunately, such a query does not sum correctly. I was contemplating the use of FIRST np. http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/417807-sql-join-question-excel-access-only-return-first-join-instance.html (użycie funkcji first) but I have no idea how to implement it so that the query should sum as expected. Thanks for hepling me out.

Comment: Note that `order by` has no influence whatsoever on the result of a `join`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use another (sub-)query to first find the longest matching category, something like:

```
SELECT TableA.descr AS aDescr, TableB.descr AS bDescr
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB on TableA.descr LIKE "*" + TableB.descr + "*"
GROUP BY TableA.descr, TableB.descr
HAVING len( TableB.descr ) = max( len( TableB.descr ) )
```

Notice the `HAVING` clause to limit the results to the longest match from `TableB`.
Once you have this dataset you can easily aggregate by `bDescr` in the next step.

Comment: MS Access doesn't understand "%" wildcard. it uses *

Comment: Good thing we have standards these days. - Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Thanks Hanno. I understood the wildcards difference and tried running it against my data.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Hanno

I tried to run your proposal and I feel it must be the right track but still it matched incorrectly:

My data:

```
ID  a   Descr   b
144 bbdd    VICRYL PLUS bbb 20
142 aacc    VICRYL PLUS aaa 20
10  dd22    VICRYL PLUS AAA     20
143 ggdc    VICRYL bbb  10
11  ss3d    VICRYL  10
```

Tried sql:

```
SELECT TableA.descr AS aDescr, TableB.descr AS bDescr
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB on TableA.descr LIKE ("*"+TableB.Descr+"*") 
GROUP BY TableA.Descr, TableB.Descr
HAVING len( TableB.Descr ) = max( len( TableB.Descr ) );
```

The match I was getting was still incorrect:
aDescr  bDescr

VICRYL         VICRYL

VICRYL bbb  VICRYL

**VICRYL PLUS AAA   VICRYL**

VICRYL PLUS AAA     VICRYL PLUS

**VICRYL PLUS bbb   VICRYL**

VICRYL PLUS bbb VICRYL PLUS

EDIT: Following Hanno's suggestion I tried removing TableB.descr from GROUP BYy. I admit I did trial and error without complete understanding. It worked only if I moved max(TableB.Descr) to Select to get rid of the message that TableB.Descr should be in GROUP BY.

Since ultimately I wanted to sum on grouped TableB.Descr what finally seems to work is:

```
SELECT major, sum(b) FROM
  (SELECT  TableA.descr as opis, max(TableB.Descr) AS major, b
   FROM TableB 
   RIGHT JOIN TableA 
   ON  TableA.Descr LIKE ("*"+TableB.Descr+"*") 
   GROUP BY  TableA.descr,b )
GROUP BY major
```

I am not marking yet as an answer. Hanno deserves more credit and I need to test it more.

Comment: This should have been an edit to your question.  If you've solved your problem you can post it as answer, but for further information/other issues it should be in the question itself.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Try it with `GROUP BY TableA.Descr` only.